# Wordpress ACF Google maps field API Key

Tags: wordpress, google-maps, advanced-custom-fields

I have a Wordpress project with Advanced Custom Fields Pro 5.3.5 plugin, where for one of my post types I set an address field using the Google Map field type. When I go to the admin page to add/edit a post this Google Maps field shows the map but in "For development purposes only" mode.

It's probably missing an API key. I'm trying to set it as described in [their documentation](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/google-map/):

```
// Method 1: Filter.
function my_acf_google_map_api( $api ){
    $api['key'] = 'xxx';
    return $api;
}
add_filter('acf/fields/google_map/api', 'my_acf_google_map_api');

// Method 2: Setting.
function my_acf_init() {
    acf_update_setting('google_api_key', 'xxx');
}
add_action('acf/init', 'my_acf_init');
```

I tried both methods in the `functions.php` of my theme and none work. I made sure that the API Key I'm using is valid and it is, I can use it on Postman to make API keys without any problem.

I've seen similar questions here on StackOverflow and basically the answer is what I'm already trying. What else I'm missing?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Are you certain that your API key is valid? That "for development purposes only" error message usually means it's a billing or API key issue. Do you have billing enabled? Please see related https://stackoverflow.com/a/57670828/11742502

Comment: Also make sure you have JavaScript API, Geocoding API and Places API enabled on your project as that plugin seems to use all three. See https://developers.google.com/maps/gmp-get-started#enable-api-sdk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just had similar issues and hopefully my solution/steps will help.
As mentioned in the comments by @evan multiple API's must be enabled in the Google Console otherwise you will get errors.

**Read the Error/Console message(s)! It will point you to either Billing or which API is not available/active.**

[image]

Troubleshooting

1. Must have Google Console Project hooked up to a billing account
2. Must enable multiple APIs
3. (optional) can restrict key to certain domain/IPs
   and also restrict to certain API

[image]

For the admin to work I required Maps Javascript API, Places API and also Geolocation API to be 'Enabled'

With those enabled my Admin could lookup and correctly assign Map lat/lng fields to the ACF field and saved correctly.

[image]