# Animaps - Google Maps For development purposes only

Tags: google-maps

I use Animaps to create a route but on the map it appears always For development purposes only.

http://www.animaps.com/#!blog

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Means you need to get and use a Google API key.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps shows “For development purposes only”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50977913/google-maps-shows-for-development-purposes-only)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Maps shows "For development purposes only"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50977913/google-maps-shows-for-development-purposes-only)

Comment: You need to use an API key and enable billing on your project https://stackoverflow.com/q/57544783/11742502

Comment: But I dont have a project! I am using this animaps website but doesnt work properly, they should use the api key

Comment: If the website and source code for the map implementation are not yours and you don't have access to it then I'm afraid you won't be able to make the map work, you'd need to contact the website's owner/developer.